# Module not found: Can't resolve firebase.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, import

[Please check the images of my vs code editor I don't know what's going on why am I getting the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBWo5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are some problems that i was also facing in firebase v9.1.2. You can downgrade to v8.6.2 and that is how i also got rid of these errors. Just paste the below code snippet in your package.json file in place of firebase module. And Google also made a number of changes when firebase v9 was released. I would highly recommend you to see the documentation as it will be the most helpful resource.
[FIREBASE V9 Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

```
"firebase": "8.6.2"
```

Comment: i am not trying to import actual firebase node module....i am tryng to import the firebase.js in src folder

Comment: So can you share your firebase,js code...Maybe you are making some kind of mistake there...

Comment: actually, I figured it out the path was import db from "./../../firebase";

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put this instead as I see your project tree:

```
import db from "../firebase";
```

Comment: i want to import firebase.js which is in src folder

Comment: Send me your git repo so I can see what's happening